# Heroku su - authentication failure

Tags: heroku, heroku-cli

I am trying to use su on heroku but not sure which password heroku uses for authentication, does anyone have an idea about this ? thank you.

Comment: I want to know which password heroku does uses for the authentication.

Comment: This is definitely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/248627). Why do you want to do this? What are you trying to do with elevated privileges? Heroku doesn't work like a plain old server.

Comment: probably, I just want to know, when I run the command su - on heroku command it asks me for a password, I entered heroku's password but it didn't work. Ii gives me an error Authentication failure.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I suspect this password isn't published anywhere. It is likely even random. I can't see any reason to ever need to do this on Heroku. "when I run the command su -"—again, _why_ are you trying to do this? What are you trying to accomplish with elevated privileges?

Answer (score 1):

> `heroku accounts:remove` » account name you have
>
> then `git config --unset heroku.account`
>
> `heroku accounts:add personal` 
> then login

Comment: I am using heroku console(over heroku.com) and all I want to do is run command heroku restart, but it gives an error like heroku command not found, and when I run command sudo command for heroku install it gives me an error sudo command not found. so that's why I am trying su - for further process.

Comment: If you're using windows , see if this works -
Go to your root directory and uninstall the ".heroku" folder .
Then reinstall the heroku toolbelt and try to log in .
Hopefully a new SSH public key will be generated and login will be successful

Comment: also you should try it
"sudo su" then
"heroku login"